# Error APT2260 resource xml/network_security_config (aka com.passxyz.vault2:xml/network_security_config) not found

Tags: android, .net, android-manifest, maui

Buenas tengo el siguiente problema en mi proyecto MAUI el AndroidManifest.xml, me dice que no encuentra el network_security_config
Esto es lo que tengo en el Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionName="0.3.1"
package="com.passxyz.vault2" android:installLocation="auto" android:versionCode="1">
    <application
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config">
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

pero la ruta esta bien
[image: Esta es ruta]

Comment: Perdon la ruta es esta /Platforms/Android/Resources/xml/network

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya esta solucionado entre en el archivo `.csproj` de la app y borre en `ItemGroup` la etiqueta `AndroidResource`; y al borrarlo , limpiar y recompilar funcion.

la etiqueta "AndroidResource" tenía definida

```
<ItemGroup> <AndroidResource Remove="Platforms\Android\Resources\xml\network_security_config.xml" /> </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: y que tenía definida la etiqueta "AndroidResource"?, te sugiero agregar esta información aquí.

Comment: tenia lo siguiente <ItemGroup>
  <AndroidResource Remove="Platforms\Android\Resources\xml\network_security_config.xml" />
</ItemGroup> y al borrarlo , limpiar y recompilar funciono

Comment: Debes [edit] tu respuesta para agregar más detalles (a eso se referían cuando dijeron "aquí"). Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Por cierto, si eres el mismo usuario que creó la pregunta, solicita [fusionar tus cuentas](/contact) en _Problema de Cuenta_ > _Necesito combinar perfiles de usuario_.

Comment: Vale gracias, por la ayuda